# When i trying to insert Query in Oracle database in am getting error?

Tags: oracle, sql-insert

When i am trying to use to insert Query in Oracle database. I am getting this below Error.

Kindly please me to resolve this issue.

```
ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
```

My Query:

```
insert into employeevalues(
 7839, 'KING', 'PRESIDENT', null,
 To_date('17-11-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),
 5000, null, 10
);
```

Comment: if values in the list conform to the data types, the lengths of the columns and constraints, and number of the columns and the orders of the columns conform, then there seems to be only one issue left that the table name and `values` keyword **has no space between them**. There is no problem with literals as having single quotes and proper time format.

Comment: To further explain the exact error you received (and the exact PLACE where the error was found: it's right at the beginning of `7839` - the error message should show that too): Since you wrote `employeevalues` as a single word, the parser thinks that's a table name. It does not see the `values` keyword; it sees an opening parenthesis. So far this is still OK, but right after that the parser expects a `SELECT` query - the other way to "insert" in a table, "INSERT INTO ... AS SELECT ..."  (not using the VALUES clause). It finds `7839` where it should see `SELECT`. That's the error (and place).

Comment: Of course, humans reading your code can spot the error immediately - it's not what the parser thinks, but the missing space before the keyword VALUES. Note that the parser finds the "invalid syntax" before it checks the catalog tables to see if you do, in fact, have a table "employeevalues". If it did, and if it told you about that non-existent table, it would have been easy for you to answer your own question. But the parser checks syntax corectness before it checks if the objects exist, so... bad luck.

Comment: The Oracle documentation is comprehensive, free and online. I suggest you bookmark it for future reference. it is easy to diagnose compilation errors like this on eby comparing our code with [the examples provided in the SQL Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9015.htm#SQLRF01604).

Answer (score 0):

space required between employee and values.
Second thing if 7839 was an autogenerated id no need to pass it.
Third one check DateTime format of the table it requires hh:mm: ss

Comment: 7839 is not auto-generated; this is the data for the standard EMP table in the SCOTT schema (which used to be installed by default with every Oracle database, for training and testing) and the EMPID is hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT statement syntax to insert a row and to give a value to each row column is:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (value1, value2, ...)
```

Try:

```
insert into employee values( 7839, 'KING', 'PRESIDENT', null, to_date('17-11-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'), 5000, null, 10 );
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26143913)

Comment: Yes it is answer: I just show a fixed syntax. I don't need to critique or ask for clarification.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.